# Unable to figure out behaviour : Method reference with lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

Consider below code,

```
class DemoStatic {
    public static Runnable testStatic() {
        return () -> {
            System.out.println("Run");
        };
    }

    public void runTest () {
        Runnable r = DemoStatic::testStatic;
        r.run();
    }
}

public class MethodReferenceDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DemoStatic demo = new DemoStatic();
        demo.runTest();
    }
}
```

`run()` method of `Runnable` instance that is being return by `testStatic` method was supposed to be invoked.
And output on console should be "Run".

But this code is not invoking `run()` method of instance `r` and nothing is getting printed in console.

Can some one please explain the reason.

And comment if I am not using Method reference "::" properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To expand a bit on Sotirios' answer:

This statement:

```
Runnable r = DemoStatic::testStatic;
```

is equivalent to

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        DemoStatic.testStatic();
    }
}
```

So `r.run()` calls a method that calls `testStatic()` to return a **new** `Runnable`, but then does nothing with it.

Comment: Yeah, that's a nicer way to visualize it. +1

Answer (score 5):

This

```
Runnable r = DemoStatic::testStatic;
```

returns a `Runnable` whose `run()` method  contains the body of the method `testStatic()`, ie.

```
public static Runnable testStatic() {
    return () -> {
        System.out.println("Run");
    };
}
```

so

```
r.run();
```

basically executes

```
return () -> {
    System.out.println("Run");
};
```

dropping the `return` value.

It's a `static` [method reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html). A method reference meaning your `Runnable` is referencing and executing the method in the method that functional interface defines.

---

For the behavior you want, you have to do

```
Runnable r = testStatic();
```

Comment: `DemoStatic::testStatic` does't this invoke the `testStatic` method ?

Comment: @KishanSarsechaGajjar It invokes the `testStatic` method in the lambda implementation's `run()` method.

Comment: @KishanSarsechaGajjar Right, `DemoStatic::testStatic` does not itself invoke `testStatic`, but rather it creates an object that is capable of invoking `testStatic` later, if you tell it to (by using `r.run()`).

Comment: so what is exact return type of "Method reference" ? Is it object reference of class that contains method ?

Comment: @KishanSarsechaGajjar A method reference only makes sense in a context that expects a functional interface and that context has to be obvious. The method reference itself doesn't have a type. When used in a context as described previously, it becomes an instance of the target interface type.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I accepted second one because it demonstrates the problem is in a bit more readable way...However your description more helpful :)

Comment: @KishanSarsechaGajjar Don't worry about that as long you understand the problem and its context.