# How to invoke parameterized method with method reference

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

Consider below code,

```
interface TestInter {
    public void abc();
}


class DemoStatic {

    public static void testStatic(String abc) {
        System.out.println(abc);
    }

    public void runTest () {

        // Using lambda expression.
        String str = "demo string" ;
        TestInter demo1 = () -> DemoStatic.testStatic(str);
        demo1.abc();

        // Using method reference.
        TestInter demo2 = DemoStatic::testStatic; // This line is not compiling.
        demo2.abc();
    }
}
```

We can invoke the `testStatic` method as body of `TestInter` interface's `abc()` implementation if parameter of `testStaic()` method will be eliminated as described in [this so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23022981/1686291).

But in this case how can we write method reference for parameterized method `testStatic`?

Comment: You can't - it doesn't fit the functional interface. What would you expect the value of the `abc` parameter to be within `testStatic`? In the lambda expression you're passing in `str`, which makes perfect sense. You could create an *adapter* between the two different method signatures (create two functional interfaces, and an adapter which called one based on the other and an extra parameter).

Comment: They didn't devise a syntax for this.  And it doesn't seem worth adding complexity to the language for it.  If you want the ability to type something like `DemoStatic::testStatic(str)`, that's really only a couple keystrokes less than the lambda expression.

Comment: @JonSkeet How it doesn't fit the functional interface ? and we are passing parameter in lambda implementation of example !! can't it be possible with method reference ?

Comment: @ajb so that is limitation of method reference, right ?

Comment: Java does not support [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) without a wrapper method/lambda.

Comment: @KishanSarsechaGajjar: The functional interface demands a method with no parameters. You're trying to use a method with a parameter. They're just not the same thing. What would you imagine would happen if you called `demo2.abc()`? What would the value of the parameter be? The lambda expression works because in the lambda expression, when you call the `testStatic` you're providing an argument (`str`). To put it another way - suppose you were writing a normal class to implement `TestInter`... would you expect to be able to implement the `abc` method with a method which took a parameter?

Comment: Remember, a lambda expression is not the same a method reference.

Comment: @JonSkeet okk...may be my concept about functional interface was wrong...I was thinking the interface with only abstract method...parameters of that method was not in picture !!! Thank you :)

Comment: @KishanSarsechaGajjar: It's a perfectly good functional interface - but it's got to be *implemented* by a method with a suitable signature.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your functional interface `TestInter` does not have corresponding signature for your `testStatic(String)` method. If you want to refer to `testStatic()` using the `::` notation, you should add the parameter:

```
interface TestInter2 {
    public void abc(String abc);
}

public void runTest () {
    TestInter2 demo2 = DemoStatic::testStatic;
    demo2.abc(str);
}
```

According to [Oracle Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), there are four kinds of method reference:

[image: Four Types of Method Reference]

I prepared 3 interfaces - for 0, 1 and 2 parameters. Then we have 3 static and 3 instance methods:

```
interface F0 {
    void f0();
}
interface F1 {
    void f1(MetRef i1);
}
interface F2 {
    void f2(MetRef i1, MetRef i2);
}

public class MetRef {
    public static void stat0() {;}
    public static void stat1(MetRef a) {;}
    public static void stat2(MetRef a, MetRef b) {;}

    public void inst0() {;}
    public void inst1(MetRef a) {;}
    public void inst2(MetRef a, MetRef b) {;}
}
```

Now look how each of the methods may be used as a method reference in various combinations, compare them with the previous table. See different method reference types in action and notice from where the parameters come.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final MetRef mr = new MetRef();

        final F0 mr01 = MetRef::stat0; // 1: f0() ~ MetRef.stat0() 
        final F0 mr02 = mr::inst0;     // 2: f0() ~ mr.inst0()
        final F0 mr04 = MetRef::new;   // 4: f0() ~ new MetRef()

        final F1 mr11 = MetRef::stat1; // 1: f1(i1) ~ MetRef.stat1(i1)
        final F1 mr12 = mr::inst1;     // 2: f1(i1) ~ mr.inst1(i1)
        final F1 mr13 = MetRef::inst0; // 3: f1(i1) ~ i1.inst0()       <== NOTICE!

        final F2 mr21 = MetRef::stat2; // 1: f2(i1, i2) ~ MetRef.stat2(i1, i2)
        final F2 mr22 = mr::inst2;     // 2: f2(i1, i2) ~ mr.inst2(i1, i2)
        final F2 mr23 = MetRef::inst1; // 3: f2(i1, i2) ~ i1.inst1(i2) <== NOTICE!
    }
}
```