# Usage of function type congruent lambda expressions in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I struggle with the definition and usage of the

```
Stream.collect(Supplier<R> supplier, BiConsumer<R,? super T> accumulator, BiConsumer<R,R> combiner)
```

[method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) in Java 8.

The method signature includes [BiConsumer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html) typed parameters. The BiConsumer FunctionalInterface defines one functional method [accept(Object, Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html#accept-T-U-). As far as I understand I can now use any lambda expression that is [congruent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3-100) to this functional interface.

But the example mentioned in the Stream.collect [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) is e.g.

```
 List<String> asList = stringStream.collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll);
```

I do not understand why [ArrayList.add(E e)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-E-) (single parameter) is congruent with the [BiConsumer.accept(T t, U u)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html#accept-T-U-) method (two parameters) and can be used as the accumulator function in the collect method.

As you see I obviously have a lack of understanding and appreciate any explanation.

Comment: it is a shortcut for `(list, element) -> list.add(element)`. There is a duplicate but I can't find it right now...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23025159/2711488 has a comprehensible illustration. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23139725/2711488) might be related as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The accumulator BiConsumer's two parameters are (1) the list itself and (2) the item to add to it. This:

```
List<String> asList = stringStream.collect(
    ArrayList::new,
    ArrayList::add,
    ArrayList::addAll
);
```

is equivalent to this:

```
List<String> asList = stringStream.collect(
    () -> new ArrayList<>(),
    (list, item) -> list.add(item),
    (list1, list2) -> list1.addAll(list2)
);
```

which will give the same result as this:

```
List<String> asList = stringStream.collect(
    new Supplier<ArrayList<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ArrayList<String> get() {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
    },

    new BiConsumer<ArrayList<String>,String>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(ArrayList<String> list, String item) {
            list.add(item);
        }
    },

    new BiConsumer<ArrayList<String>,ArrayList<String>>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(ArrayList<String> list1, ArrayList<String> list2) {
            list1.addAll(list2);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: As correct as @Misha s answer but a bit more detail - thus accepted

Answer (score 10):

`ArrayList::add` actually has 2 parameters.  The `ArrayList` object on which you call the `add` method and the parameter to `add`.

`ArrayList::add` is equivalent to `(list, element) -> list.add(element)` and so it works as a `BiConsumer`